# Windows 8 and 7 NTFS drive incompatibility

Tags: windows-8, ntfs

I have a DELL XPS L702x, which has two 2,5" drive bays. I had a Windows 7 Ultimate on it for near a year, then, when Win8 came to be, i bought another SSD and installed it. Not dual-boot, just pulled out older drive, installed new system and replaced Win7 again. Now i have to press some key at startup that allows me to choose which drive to boot, which is fine.

PROBLEM:
When i get to Win8, and then get back to Win7, i get CHKDSK at bootup, saying that ALL PARTITIONS on ALL DRIVES are unusable, including these system reserved (both of my drives have one), so i should check them. So i do. Most of the time there's only some message of the "removed unused entries in index xxx file 0x9", but at some point i **lost some data that was on Win7 drive!** because of cross-linked files.

Now i got to Win8 again and it says i have to reboot to run chkdsk offline, because it detected some corruption on Win8 drive.

Seems to me that it will be infinite scanning of random drives. So there comes a question - is there some new feature in Win8, so that when you put win8 drive in Win7 machine it will be considered damaged and vice-versa? Both my drives are SSD and one of them, the older one (Win7), has already 9 reallocated sectors. If i run Win7 only, then chkdsk does not appear, ever. As soon as i run Win8 - there it is.

Anyway, i'm stumped. I welcome any suggestions and wild guesses as to what may be the problem.

Comment: i had similar issue, after installing windows 7 with win xp on same drive. Even though i removed win xp sometime later, that error didnt go. So i had to format my driver, and make new partitions

Comment: What is not clear is the reason you have files that are cross-linked with one another.

Comment: @Ramhound I know, i would scan the drive one time and everything is OK, then switch OS-es and have from minor problems to data loss... I even got DELL's driver for Intel Rapid Storage, even though Win8 installed the newer version.

Comment: I have had this experience on two different systems. The only way to avoid it was using a boot manager (I use BootIt BareMetal) that can hide the other partitions. I am pretty sure there is a bug in Win8 but everything I have seen on MS support claims otherwise. Since I have seen little real value in Windows 8 I just don't even bother with booting it anymore.

Comment: @jtreser i need it for programing, rarely launched but need to check if my programs run properly and such.

Comment: I understand - I test software so that is the only reason I didnt delete the partition. The boot manager I use is here: http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/bootit-bare-metal.htm
it allows you to selectively hide partitions at boot and that should work. It seemed to solve the issue for me but like I said I had not been using Win8 much since.

Comment: By the way i just found that tool DiskExplorer from Runtime, which told me which files were cross-linked. 1 files in Win7 c:\Windows\winsxs\Temp\PendingRenames folder. 2 files in my Win7 Firefox cache dir. Many files few days ago were in the ProgramData\Microsoft\Search. These are temp files. And the file 0x9 is $Secure in the root of the drive, if anyone wants to know. Oh, and one time Win7 would CHKDSK both SSDs and Win8 wouldn't then start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search Google for: `chkdsk incompatibility in Windows 7 Windows 8 dual boot`.

See the answer below found in [this site](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d5604d5c-e56c-4dd4-889a-b592e8846e41/chkdsk-incompatibility-in-windows-7-windows-8-dual-boot?forum=w8itproinstall):

> Windows 8 is designed to close and reopen by faster booting (Hybrid Boot), it has left your system in a hibernated state, with the drives mounted, open and ready to take off as soon as Windows 8 restarts. When a drive is mounted, a little piece of data is written to a standard place on the disk to show it is in use - it is called the "dirty bit".
>
> This means that the "dirty bit" on the disks that Windows 7 checks on startup is showing on the disks. And then, chkdsk is automatically run to check the integrity of the disks with the "dirty bit" set. Please check the following settings. (In Windows 8, 8.1 and maybe 10)
>
> 1. Control Panel -> Power Plan
> 2. Select "Choose what the power button does" on left hand side.
> 3. Click on "Change settings that are currently unavailable".
> 4. Uncheck "Turn on fast startup" under shutdown settings.

Comment: That's true, I've already known that, after all, it is 4 years since I asked this Q. I can confirm that turning off e.g. hibernation alltogether stopped these errors too, since fast startup (and probably hybrid sleep) were options that needed hibernation.